# Spring Boot Kafka Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

If you look at the official documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/receiving-messages/listener-annotation.html) and pretty much every example on the internet, *KafkaListenerContainerFactory* in Spring Boot is configured this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>>
                        kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
                                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

}
```

Note that *kafkaListenerContainerFactory()* method instead of accepting *ConsumerFactory* bean as a parameter, calls *consumerFactory()* method, creating second instance of the *ConsumerFactory* class and defeating purpose of the bean, declared next to this method.

Why is this done this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not correct. If you use `@Configuration` without `proxyBeanMethods = false`:

```
/**
 * Specify whether {@code @Bean} methods should get proxied in order to enforce
 * bean lifecycle behavior, e.g. to return shared singleton bean instances even
 * in case of direct {@code @Bean} method calls in user code. This feature
 * requires method interception, implemented through a runtime-generated CGLIB
 * subclass which comes with limitations such as the configuration class and
 * its methods not being allowed to declare {@code final}.
 * <p>The default is {@code true}, allowing for 'inter-bean references' via direct
 * method calls within the configuration class as well as for external calls to
 * this configuration's {@code @Bean} methods, e.g. from another configuration class.
 * If this is not needed since each of this particular configuration's {@code @Bean}
 * methods is self-contained and designed as a plain factory method for container use,
 * switch this flag to {@code false} in order to avoid CGLIB subclass processing.
 * <p>Turning off bean method interception effectively processes {@code @Bean}
 * methods individually like when declared on non-{@code @Configuration} classes,
 * a.k.a. "@Bean Lite Mode" (see {@link Bean @Bean's javadoc}). It is therefore
 * behaviorally equivalent to removing the {@code @Configuration} stereotype.
 * @since 5.2
 */
boolean proxyBeanMethods() default true;
```

Then all the `@Bean` methods in this class are proxied and whenever we call them, the instance is created only once.

The argument injection is really better since we don't go through the proxy, but that's already out of Spring for Apache Kafka scope. And I believe those samples over there for in a bean method calls style is rather for better comprehension than performance and so on.

It also the fact that with Spring Boot you might not need those factory beans since they are just auto-configured. However it doesn't mean that you always go with Spring Boot. Therefore plain Spring for Apache Kafka samples tend to be full of info.